# C++ values not updating from thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, struct

I have made the following struct:

```
struct CLICKING {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point lastClickTime;

    void clickMouse() {
        /* click mouse stuff here */
        lastClickTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Setting last click time to " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(lastClickTime) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

In my main class, I create the struct:

```
std::unique_ptr<CLICKING> clickingPtr = std::make_unique<CLICKING>();
clickingPtr->lastClickTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
```

And then in a Windows thread (using `CreateThread`), I have something like this (in an infinite loop):

```
std::cout << "Last click time in thread: " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(inst->getClickDetails().lastClickTime) << std::endl;
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - inst->getClickDetails().lastClickTime).count();

....

// At some point, if factors are correct, click the mouse:
inst->getClickDetails().clickMouse();
```

`inst` refers to `this`, just passed into the thread, and `getClickDetails()` grabs the `unique_ptr`. However, after all of this, I get the same thing printed out:
`Last click time in thread: 1592999354`

but every time I do call for `clickMouse()` I can see:
`Setting last click time to 1592999377`.

It seems that `lastClickTime` is only being set the first time (when creating the `unique_ptr`) but on subsequent calls to set it it updates within the struct (as seen from the struct printout) but asking for its value in the thread it does not update...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Long story short - you are in realms of undefined behaviour. Why? Because you are causing data race by reading and writing to unsynchronized memory via multiple threads. What it means? It means your program may behave in completely unpredictable ways which happened as you noticed posting it here. How to fix it? One possibility is using `std::mutex` like that:

```
struct CLICKING {
    std::chrono::system_clock::time_point lastClickTime;
    std::mutex mtx;

    void clickMouse() {
        /* click mouse stuff here */
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{mtx};
        lastClickTime = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
        std::cout << "Setting last click time to " << std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(lastClickTime) << std::endl;
    }
};
```

```
std::cout << "Last click time in thread: " << 
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{inst->getClickDetails().mtx};
std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(inst->getClickDetails().lastClickTime) << std::endl;
auto elapsed = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now - inst->getClickDetails().lastClickTime).count();
```

Comment: So I added the mutex in but I am getting a runtime error when trying to lock in in the struct function: `Exception Unhandled: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFA2DD0A799 in project.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::system_error at memory location0x0000003A5A8FF210.` Any idea why? happens right after I call `std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l{ mtx };`